# Formatting an doubel like xxxxE+xx in C

Tags: c, formatting, double

How can you format an double like 12345.0 to be printed as 1.234E+04?
I want to print something like this:

```
int N = 1024;
int time = 3476;
printf("%f", (N/time));
```

Where the output would be: `3.394531E+00`

Comment: To begin with, don't use integer operations (whose result is an `int`). To continue, see e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: And don't pass integer arguments for `%f` type specifier in `printf`

Comment: And use `%e`.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented and answered by others [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47413842/formatting-an-doubel-like-xxxxexx-in-c#comment81780998_47413842): perform the division using floating-point math and not integer math.

Insure the correct `a/b` vs `b/a` is done to achieve "output would be: 3.394531E+00"

Use the `"%.nE"` format (where `n` is the precession) to print in exponential notation.  `"%E"` alone will act like `"%.6E"`.

`"%e"` is like  `"%E"` except is uses an `'e'` vs. `'E'` in the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int N = 1024;
  int time = 3476;
  printf("%.6E\n", 1.0*N/time);
  printf("%.6E\n", 1.0*time/N);
  printf("%.3E\n", 12345.0);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
2.945915E-01
3.394531E+00
1.234E+04
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either use `float` for your variables or cast some of the variables to floating-point type like this:

```
printf("%f", ((float)N/time));
```

If you want to have your numbers always in *Scientific notation* http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ you can replace the format with "%e".

It's worth noting that `printf` expects `double` by default for all `f F e E g G a A`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to avoid the integer division. Cast `N` to a double for instance (then the division will be with decimals).

And use the `%e` format (`%E` for a big-e), for 6 decimals:

```
printf("%.6E", (double)N/time);
```